# Is RAID-0 noticeable in a programming environment?

Tags: java, ssd

I use my computer mainly for programming - Java, IntelliJ IDEA.. it's a bit of a slow IDE, especially on opening a project / loading up the IDE. I also use the eclipse compiler with it, but there are still some make operations that are slowish.

Would I feel a noticeable difference (core i7 desktop 32GB), if I installed 2 SSD in a RAID-0 configuration? Does anyone know the answer?

It's not really a question of the money, just seems stupid if I won't get any benefits.. if I will get some noticeable benefits then it would be interesting.

Comment: Unless you know for sure your tools are I/O-bound, any answer would be a guess.

Comment: A single SSD is likely sufficient.

Comment: Do you already have an SSD drive running your OS and IDE?  If not, this upgrade alone should show huge improvement.

Comment: One good SSD should be plenty

Comment: yes, sure - I have an older generation SSD - OCZ Vertex 3 480GB (530MBps/450MBps) .. just really wondering why the load time is so long ... I also strangely notice my 1TB regular drive thrashes during this load process... not really sure why.. only noticed that particular aspect (the 1TB media & File History backup drive) today, so I need to investigate further

Comment: kinda stupid the question got moved though.. I asked it in programmers because I wanted the opinion of programmers - hopefully familiar with that particular IDE - instead it gets labelled as a possible duplicate of a general question asked on a different site, whereas this is a specific use case question. Kinda like if I asked a question about oranges and it gets labelled as a duplicate of a question about fruits. So what I'm taking away from this now is - maybe yes, maybe no

Answer (score 1):

RAID-0 provides only more bandwidth, unless you work with large files (multiple gigabytes, like movies) then faster SSD (more IOPS) fill be better that RAID-0 made from slower devices.

Comment: as a side note, why exactly is it better for gaming? I mean the games can still run on normal hard drives or single SSDs... I see the gaming notebooks are big on it - I'm tempted to get a gaming notebook for work (not gaming)

Comment: @Mikey: Probably because most games nowadays load many megabytes of textures and background images. More bandwidth = smoother operation.